# How to use a function as a criteria in COUNTIF

Tags: google-sheets

I have a bunch of columns that holds scores like `3-1` `1-4` `1-0` `2-2`.

I would like to count all columns that are winning, ie. left number is higher than right one.

I have this formula to know if a column is winning : `=LEFT(H2; FIND("-"; H2)-1)-RIGHT(H2; FIND("-"; H2)-1)`

What I want to do now is to use this formula within `COUNTIF`, something along the line :

`=COUNTIF(A1:A10; "LEFT(CURRENT_COLUMN; FIND("-"; CURRENT_COLUMN)-1)-RIGHT(CURRENT_COLUMN; FIND("-"; CURRENT_COLUMN)-1)")`

Is there any way I can do it with a single formula ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex filtering like this can be done with `filter`, and then the results can be counted with `counta`. Example:

```
=counta(filter(A:A, LEFT(A:A, FIND("-", A:A)-1) > RIGHT(A:A, FIND("-", A:A)-1)))
```

The first argument of `filter` is the range to be filtered; the second is a formula based on that range (or another range with the same row count) which returns True or False. The rows where the formula evaluates to True are returned.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited your answer since my question is aimed towards google spreadsheet. You used `,` instead of `;` to separate arguments

Comment: Google Sheets uses either `,` or `;` to separate arguments, it depends on the user's locale. In my locale it's the comma.